# Using microsoft chess in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

I want to use microsoft chess framework in visual studio 2010. it works fine in 2008 but its support is not available for visual studio 2010. is there any way to use it.

Comment: What is the chess framework? is it this? http://chesstool.codeplex.com/ in this case, VS 2010 seems supported.

Comment: this doesnt have any releases in downloads section, yes this is the framework. used for testing multithreaded applications,

Comment: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/chess/download.aspx here there is not present download for visual studio 2010.

Answer (score 6):

Just go there: [CHESS: Systematic Concurrency Testing Source Code](http://chesstool.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets), click on the 'Download' button, read the licence text and if you're ok download the full package somewhere on your disk.

From there you can just extract the whole .ZIP file and open the `All.Sln` file at the root of the extracted files, it's a Visual Studio 2010 solution.